# Change the highlight color in Elementary OS

Tags: linux, elementary-os, theme

When I hover the mouse in buttons or dropdown menus, the text's color changed to white but also the background of the text changed to white and make it unreadable. Look at the image in the right click menu of the mouse. The white area is the "save as" option and I have the mouse hovering it.

Also, I have another problem, probably related with this one. When I have a form with radio buttons, I cannot see the checked one if the buttons are white. Probably the dot in the checked on is white and I cannot recognize which one is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem. The solution was editing the theme style files. 
An example how to change the font color for the desktop can be found [here](http://elementaryos.org/answers/how-to-change-the-desktop-font-color).

The file responsible for the look of selected menu entries is the `gtk.css` under `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0`

The Line:

```css
@define-color selected_fg_color #FFF;
```

defines the text color for selected text as white. Just change the #FFF to some color you like and logout and login again and it should be fixed.